# Vue 3 Swiper ignores styles

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to customize the next and previous swiper slide arrows, change their colors, give them padding and font size..etc, but the swiper totally ignores my styles, i don't even see them in chrome dev-tools, why is that happening?

```html
<script setup>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/effect-cards";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import { EffectCards, Keyboard, Navigation } from "swiper/modules";
</script>

<template>
  <swiper
    :effect="'cards'"
    :grabCursor="true"
    :modules="[EffectCards, Keyboard, Navigation]"
    class="mySwiper mt-5"
    :navigation="true"
  >
    <swiper-slide v-for="product in props.products">
      <Link type="button" as="button" :href="route('product', product.name)">
        <img :src="product.imageUrl" alt="" />
      </Link>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

<style scoped>
.swiper {
    width: 240px; // works
    height: 320px; // works
}
.swiper-button-next:after {
    font-size: 1000px; // not applied
    background-color: #000; // not applied
    color: #000; // not applied
    margin: 1000px; // not applied
    padding: 1000px; // not applied
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that is rendered by your component? The JS code you posted doesn't explain why the `.swiper` selector is working while the selector for the button `.swiper-button-next:after` is not. From what I see no style should apply because no classname matches right now.

Comment: its not my class, i spectated the previous and next arrows of the swiper, they have their own pre-classes, i applied these styles to the class, but as i said, doesn't apply.

Comment: if you import ```{ Navigation }``` component and apply it like this ```:modules="[Navigation]"```, it will apply the arrows to the component, it also got its own styles imported, i updated my post for imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that swiper ignores the styles, it's that the current component's CSS does not apply to inner DOM elements of the `<swiper />` component because ***you*** have scoped it (to better understand what scoping does look in page source for the generated styles, observe the generated selectors and inspect the DOM elements of your component).

Scoping in Vue works so that the scoped styles are only applied to the DOM elements of the current component, not to any of its siblings (even when they have exactly the same classes), nor to any of the DOM elements of its child components (except for the root elements of the child components, because those are technically DOM elements of current component).
And `.swiper-button-next` is a DOM sub-element of `<swiper />` component, so it's not scoped to your component.

Technically, CSS scoping is achieved by applying a `v-{uniqueComponentIdentifier}` attribute to all the DOM elements of current component and applying this selector (`[v-{uniqueComponentIdentifier}]` to every selector of the component's generated styles.

There are multiple ***alternative*** ways to fix it:

1. remove the `scoped` attribute (note that all of the component's CSS becomes global in this case, which you might not want)
2. or add another `<style>` (without `scoped`) and move all the code you want applied globally into it, and leave the CSS you want scoped inside the current `<style scoped>`
3. or wrap the selectors you want to unscope in `:v-global()`; e.g:

```html
<style scoped>
:v-global(.swiper-button-next:after) {
  font-size: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #000;
  margin: 1000px;
  padding: 1000px;
}
</style>
```

---

Notes:

- `:v-global` is an alias for `:v-deep`.
- read more about [scoped CSS](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css) and [deep selectors](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors) in Vue.